# JNLP Error with JaNeLA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jnlp, java-web-start

I have downloaded a jnlp file from [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) and I have downloaded the JaNeLA from [Here](http://pscode.org/janela/)
When I analyze the file I have got following errors.

This is the text report

```
JaNeLA Report - version 11.05.17


    Report for file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Administrator/Desktop/sample.jnlp

    Content type application/xml does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file
    The element type "homepage" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</homepage>".
```

I know the error are straight forwards but I am not able to resolve them and believe my I have tried my best. Can anyone help?

Here is my JNLP file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- JNLP File for SwingSet2 Demo Application -->
<jnlp   spec="6.0+"   codebase="http://my_company.com/jaws/apps"   href="swingset2.jnlp" >
  <information>
    <title>SwingSet2 Demo Application</title>
    <vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</vendor>
    <homepage href="docs/help.html" />
    <description>SwingSet2 Demo Application</description>
    <description kind="short">A demo of the capabilities 
    of the Swing Graphical User Interface.</description>
    <icon href="images/swingset2.jpg"/>
    <icon kind="splash" href="images/splash.gif"/>
    <offline-allowed/> 
    <association mime-type="application-x/swingset2-file"  extensions="swingset2"/> 
    <shortcut online="false">
      <desktop/>
      <menu submenu="My Corporation Apps"/>
    </shortcut>
  </information>

  <information os="linux">   
    <title> SwingSet2 Demo on Linux </title>
    <homepage href="docs/linuxhelp.html">
  </information>

  <security>
      <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" java-vm-args="-esa -Xnoclassgc"/>
    <jar href="lib/SwingSet2.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="SwingSet2"/>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: @Andrew: Belive me sir I am very big fan of yours and Here is the text report from you tool. JaNeLA Report - version 11.05.17


Report for file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Administrator/Desktop/sample.jnlp

Content type application/xml does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file
The element type "homepage" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</homepage>".

Comment: @AndrewThompson and I would like to know how to fix the first error "Content type application/xml does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file"

Comment: `<information os="linux">   
    <title> SwingSet2 Demo on Linux </title>
    <homepage href="docs/linuxhelp.html">` - **That** should be terminated with a `/`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Thanks a lot and I am interested to know how to fix the first problem "Content type application/xml does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file" I understand it is a warning but I would like to my jnlp to be perfect for JaNela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am interested to know how to fix the first problem

```
Content type application/xml does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file
```

The JaNeLA [help](http://pscode.org/janela/help.html) suggests:

> The content-type or MIME type of the application was not the expected type.
>
> - If this error is being returned from a real live server, it causes the client browser to simply display the content of the JNLP files as XML in the browser! Contact the server administraters to add the content-type.
> - It is typical for JNLP files checked from the **local file system** to be of incorrect type.

The source of that JNLP is:

```
file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Administrator/Desktop/sample.jnlp
```

..so you can safely ignore that warning.

### Other problem

As mentioned n a comment.

```
  <information os="linux">   
    <title> SwingSet2 Demo on Linux </title>
    <homepage href="docs/linuxhelp.html">
  </information>
```

**That** `homepage` element should be terminated with a `/`, like this:

```
  <information os="linux">   
    <title> SwingSet2 Demo on Linux </title>
    <homepage href="docs/linuxhelp.html"/>
  </information>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the nice and simple explaination

Answer (score 2):

Also, you didn't close the `homepage` tag. Try this:

```
<homepage href="docs/linuxhelp.html"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem can be ignored. It is because the jnlp was retrieved from the file system, rather than a web server.

The [JaNeLA help page](http://pscode.org/janela/help.html) says this:

> Warning   Content type application/xml does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file
>   The content-type or MIME type of the application was not the expected type.

```
If this error is being returned from a real live server, it causes the client browser to simply display the content of the JNLP files as XML in the browser! Contact the server administraters to add the content-type.
It is typical for JNLP files checked from the local file system to be of incorrect type.
```